# why would Python (2.7) OR boolean operators return True incorrectly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently teaching myself Python 2.7 though an online course, and having a bit of trouble with a boolean operator. The context is a very simple - a closed text based adventure game (which takes all of 30 seconds to run).

I've added the following if statement to allow for different user inputs -  however even in instances where say the input is say, "gobbledigook", or "right", for which there is an **elif** statement, the *bear_room()* function is still called. Am I misusing the OR function here?
Apologies if this has already been answered somewhere, the checks on boolean logic I did only confirmed my current thinking, so didn't help much!

```
choice = raw_input()    
if choice == "left" or "Left" or "LEFT":
            bear_room()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `if choice == "left" or choice == "Left" ...`

But, you can just simplify your condition to use `if choice.lower() == 'left'`

Comment: That's great! I've been at this all day - can't believe I missed such a simple syntax thing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The other answer explains more in depth and why this happens. i.e. - your other `or`'s actually evaluate to True

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the `or` operator - it does a logical OR on boolean values - that's it either `True` or `False`. Your expression on the other hand mixes types - let's break it down:

- `choice == "left"` is a boolean
- `'Left'` is a string. The `or` operator cannot work on strings so it tries to convert it to a boolean. It does so by checking whether it's empty - any nonempty string is converted to `True`, empty strings are converted to `False`
- 'left' - same as above

After the string-to-boolean conversions, your expression becomes

```
if choice == "left" or True or True:
            bear_room()
```

It's now clear why any input causes `bear_room` to execute. To properly handle your case you can any of the following:

```
if choice == 'left' or choice == 'Left' or choice == 'LEFT':
    bear_room()
if choice.lower() == 'left': # convert all letters to lower case
    bear_room()
if choice in ['left', 'Left', 'LEFT']: # check choice is in the list of valid options
    bear_room()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. Frustrated with myself for missing it now!